# Running Python script from cmd line but start with import in code

Tags: python, command-line, import

I am running a Python script from Linux command line, and the script itself, on the first line, import several modules. I got some error message and searched online. Here is a reply from the author of the Python script:

it appears that you are running `dexseq_count.py` as if it were a shell script, rather than from Python. As a consequence, the first line of the script is interpreted as the Linux command 'import' rather than as Python code, leading to the error you report.

I am curious if the first line of `import` in Python has been mis-interpretated in Linux, and if so, how can I solve this problem? I have to run in the cmd line instead of in Python.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you calling the python interpreter? `python dexseq_count.py`? or just executing like this `./dexseq_count.py`?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen i use the latter one ;-)

Comment: Then you need to follow @Paco advice and make sure you specify the interpreter at the top of your script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two solutions here:
You can run the script using python like this: `python my_program.py` or  add this at the top of the file: `#!/usr/bin/env python` which will switch from bash to python to run this script

Comment: You're welcome. You can now award the answer as it may help other people to know you've found the solution